# Is there way to save image to hard drive from Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Long time ago I`ve created Google Sheet with imported images. But now I need to edit them. Is there some way to save to hard drive?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: No there isn't one.